# how to disable ExpandableListView Accessibility announcement (Talkback)

Tags: listview, expandablelistview, talkback

I have an issue with `ExpandableListView` overlay another view.
I tried to disable the `ExpandableListView` by:

```
public void isAccisability(boolean isActive)
{
    expandableListCategories.setEnabled(false);

   expandableListCategories.setImportantForAccessibility
   (View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
    expandableListCategories.setFocusable(false);   
}
```

I was able to disable the on click but the contentdescription of the list is still working and the focusing as well.

Comment: Please format your code as code (intend at least 4 spaces) and you wille increase the chance to get a better anser.

Comment: Fixed code-formatting, improved wording

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide an entire view with subviews you want to use NODE_HIDE_DESCENDANTS.

```
view.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);
```